# Azure form recognizer error: "Failed to download image from input URL."

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-layout) to use the layout form recognizer service from Azure 
Which have the following code:

```
########### Python Form Recognizer Async Layout #############

import json
import time
from requests import get, post

# Endpoint URL
endpoint = r"<Endpoint>"
apim_key = "<Subscription Key>"
post_url = endpoint + "/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/Layout/analyze"
source = r"<path to your form>"

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apim_key,
}
with open(source, "rb") as f:
    data_bytes = f.read()

try:
    resp = post(url = post_url, data = data_bytes, headers = headers)
    if resp.status_code != 202:
        print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % resp.text)
        quit()
    print("POST analyze succeeded:\n%s" % resp.headers)
    get_url = resp.headers["operation-location"]
except Exception as e:
    print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % str(e))
    quit()
```

I tried the code I got the following error:

```
POST analyze failed:
{"error":{"code":"FailedToDownloadImage","message":"Failed to download image from input URL."}}
POST analyze succeeded:
{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '4', 'apim-request-id': '515e93ee-4db8-4174-92b1-63e5c415c056', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Sat, 06 Jun 2020 20:47:28 GMT'}
POST analyze failed:
'operation-location'
```

The code I'm using is:

```
import json
import time
from requests import get, post
```

I'm reading the pdf file before making the request and verifying it loaded into the variable

```
source = r"data/Invoice_7.pdf" 
with open(source, "rb") as f:
    data_bytes = f.read()

print (data_bytes[0:10])
```

Then the request details:

```
endpoint = r"https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

apim_key = "xxxx"
post_url = endpoint + "/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/Layout/analyze"

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apim_key,
}
```

And finally making the request:

```
try:
    resp = post(url = post_url, data = data_bytes, headers = headers)
    print (1)
    if resp.status_code != 202:
        print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % resp.text)
        #quit()
    print (2)
    print("POST analyze succeeded:\n%s" % resp.headers)
    print (3)
    get_url = resp.headers["operation-location"]
    print (4)
except Exception as e:
    print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % str(e))
    #quit()
```

I'm printing a number at each step because I find very weird that I get both fail and successful requests responses. This is the result:

```
1
POST analyze failed:
{"error":{"code":"FailedToDownloadImage","message":"Failed to download image from input URL."}}
2
POST analyze succeeded:
{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '1', 'apim-request-id': '93a2a162-d14f-496f-ba8a-077bcfd5d3c7', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Sat, 06 Jun 2020 21:00:20 GMT'}
3
POST analyze failed:
'operation-location'
```

So the code fails at this line:

```
get_url = resp.headers["operation-location"]
```

the text in the response variable is:

```
'{"error":{"code":"FailedToDownloadImage","message":"Failed to download image from input URL."}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As defined in the REST API documentation](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeLayoutAsync), you need to specify the Content-Type. When you set your Content-Type to `application/json`, you need to provide a public accessible source via JSON. In your case, you need to set the Content-Type to `application/pdf`. When you want to make this dynamic, you could make use of the PyPi package [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/).

By the way, did you know that there is a [(beta) Python SDK for Form Recognizer,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python) which you can use for your use-case.

Comment: That solvel the Issue for pdf, Now I tried with an image as: application/png and I get this error:  "code":"BadArgument","message":"Unsupported media type."

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez please have a look at the [documentation](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeLayoutAsync) I linked. You need to use the [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) for `Content-Type`, which is `image/png` for example. My advice would be to make use of [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/), instead of hardcoding this in your script.